# socketio client: How to connect socketio

Tags: windows-phone-8, websocket, socket.io

first of all thanks for read this post.
I nedd connect to a SocketIO from windows phone 8 and i dont know how to do it, If someone know it please post a solution, thanks for read this.
PD.: I used SocketIO4Net but i cant add the nudget to my project.

Comment: I can conect to the socket using websocket4net but i cant connect to the socket after disconnect to it... the library that i use is: https://github.com/Ayaro/SocketIO4Net.wp7

Comment: did you look into the WP8 Sockets API? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202874(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: Yes, i look it and it connect to the socket but dont recive any message and the server is sending messages anytime...

Comment: the socket is a websocket and i try to connect to it using websocket4net but i cant connect...

Comment: I resolve the problem using websocket4net. I had create a library with the solution. https://github.com/esccriru/SimpleSocketIONet

Answer (score 1):

I used a different library, SockeIOClientDotNet, I installed through the NuGEt manager interface. 
In order to connect to a nodeJs server I did this and it worked:

```
public Socket socket;
public theConstructor(){
    this.InitializeComponent();
    socket = IO.Socket(EVENT_CONNECT,()=>{
    socket.Emit("xyz", "a message sent to nodeJs");
});
}
```